# Graphing a function using derivatives, how do I compute the relationship?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Here is the question I am stuck on:

Suppose $f(3)=2$, $f'(3)=1/2$, and $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)<0$ for all x?

a) How many solutions does the equation $f(x)=0$ have? Why?

b) Is it possible that $f'(2)=1/3?$ why?

I know that the function is increasing only, but also concaving down. I'm not sure how to graph this function. I'm thinking there would be only one solution for $f(x) = 0 $ because it will pass through the graph once. For b, I don't think this would be possible as $f'(2)$ > $f'(3)$.

Answer (score 0):

***HINTS***

Do you really ***need*** to graph it in order to answer the two questions?

For the first since $f'\gt0$ $\forall x$ we have that $f$ is strictly increasing so the equation $f(x)=0$ can have at most one solution.

Concerning the second question you seem to be on to something-again no need for a graph!-but can you elaborate?

Comment: Well it is asked that I sketch a possible graph, and I'm not sure how to insert a graph into my question. The second question, $f''(x)\lt0$ so $f'(x)$ decreases always, so my thought was that $f'(2)$ must be greater than $f'(3)$. So, the above question for b would be impossible.